# How to create a layout with fixed content on the left and expending visual/image on the right?

Tags: html, css, layout

While doing a header section I encountered a problem while creating a layout that should contain text and a visual image.

In the header, the text and image should stack on mobile (text first and below it the image) which works fine but the problem arises on desktop screen widths where the text on the left should be aligned with the section below it (width of 1200px) I created an example image of what I'm trying to achieve and a Codepen link. I tried to achieve this with CSS Grid but the text moves as the screen width increases/decreases.

Thank you in advance and if additional info is needed plz feel free to ask.

[image]

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/IMiljancic/pen/OJpoLxQ)

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header__content">
        <div class="header__content-copy">
            <h1>Pellentesque vitae congue mi, non rhoncus erat.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__visual"></div>
</div>
<div class="text">
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque hendrerit
    quam justo. Aliquam cursus tortor et leo tincidunt, ac ullamcorper libero pellentesque. Phasellus sed varius turpis.
    Vestibulum eget metus eu leo commodo condimentum. Phasellus quis tempor metus, ut elementum odio. Nam id tempor sem.
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.header {
    display: grid;
    background-color: #f54748;

    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    }

    &__content {
        padding: 40px 10px 40px 20px;

        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            padding: 80px 40px 120px 40px;
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
            padding: 100px 40px 250px 120px;
        }
    }

    &__content-copy {
        color: #fee;
        max-width: 320px;
        h1 {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            max-width: 600px;
            h1 {
                font-size: 32px;
                line-height: 48px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
            max-width: 700px;
            h1 {
                font-size: 56px;
                line-height: 64px;
            }
        }
    }

    &__visual {
        background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/201/656/645");
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100px;

        @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
            margin-left: 100px;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
}

.text {
    padding: 40px 20px;
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't removing `max-width` and `margin` from your `.text` solve the problem? You'll only need to increase the x-paddings to about 120px after that.

Comment: Removing the `max-width` and adding `padding` of 120px would result that on resolutions like 1920px the width of `.text` would be 1920px - 240px per side so 1680px... but it should be 1200px

Comment: `.text {
  padding: 40px 120px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the top container and bottom container the same padding left.

Also the image can be whatever size you want, I just gave it a fixed size so that it appears small in the preview.

```css
.top-section {
display: flex;
}

.top-section .text {
padding: 40px;
}

.bottom-section {
padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="top-section">
        <div class="text">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img width="300" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623171826791-b2b77127b589?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-section">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
        a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at
        its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as
        opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing
        packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum'
        will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by
        accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    </div>
</div>
```